# Trouble with multiple inheritance and multiprocessing (arguments are not passed to target function)

Tags: python, discord, multiprocessing

So I am trying to do some multiprocessing with discord bots and I am having some trouble with starting the bot. And i am not really sure what is wrong? This is my code:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import tasks
import multiprocessing

class MyProcess(discord.Client, multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(
        self, intents, arguments, *args, **kwargs
    ):
        discord.Client.__init__(self, intents=intents)
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, target=self.run, kwargs=arguments)

    def start_process(self):
        super(multiprocessing.Process, self).start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=180)
    async def some_task(self):
        pass



proc = MyProcess(
    intents=discord.Intents.default(),
    arguments={"token": "TOKEN"}
)

proc.start_process()
```

And the error I keep getting is:

```
TypeError: Client.run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'token'
```

I initialize both inherited classes correctly but it looks like the Process doesn't pass arguments to Client.run() method?

Comment: Process expects the arguments to be passed as positional, not as kwargs. Try doing `multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, target=self.run, args=(token,))`.

Comment: @ArtieVandelay I have already tried this. I think the problem might be that `Process.start()` by default calls `self.run`, which is overridden by `run` from `discord.Client`. So when `start()` is called it calls `run` from discord.Client without arguments. Is that possible?

Comment: Could very well be. Is there any reason why you specifically want multiple inheritance for this case? I try to avoid it because you always get unexpected behavior. Why not let your class inherit from Client, and start your Process separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the Method Resolution Order (MRO) for `MyProcess` searches for the `run` function in class `discord.Client` first, and then the `Process` class. Since `Client` class also has a run function, doing `Process.start` will run that function instead internally. You can check this by doing:

```
`print(MyProcess.__mro__)`
```

**Output**:

```
(<class '__main__.MyProcess'>, <class 'discord.client.Client'>, <class 'multiprocessing.context.Process'>, <class 'multiprocessing.process.BaseProcess'>, <class 'object'>)
```

A simple fix here is to shift the process class to the left hand side so the MRO changes to search the attributes inside `Process` class first. Then, you just need to pass `run` explicitly when instantiating the `Process` class:

```
class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process, discord.Client):  # Process class comes first
    def __init__(
        self, intents, arguments, *args, **kwargs
    ):
        discord.Client.__init__(self, intents=intents)
        
        # Pass self as an argument and specify explicitly which "run" we want as the target function 
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, target=discord.Client.run, args=(self, ), kwargs=arguments)

    def start_process(self):
        super(multiprocessing.Process, self).start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=180)
    async def some_task(self):
        pass
```

But a better fix would be to perhaps not use multiple inheritance if the classes were not *especially designed* keeping that in mind. There are alot of issues you can run into otherwise. So, make sure that you absolutely need to inherit the `Process` class before committing to such a design.